# How to determine the article PDF download link from the article webpage?

Tags: python-3.x, html-parsing, bioinformatics

I would like to download some articles from my DOI list automatically (about 1500). Using [doi.org](https://doi.org) I can get a website content for every of them. But the problem is that every website is unique and I do not know how to determine a download link amongst a number of hrefs. Please, could you suggest anything useful for such aim in Python?

P. S. The speech is about free access articles. So I can be sure that the link exists.

Comment: This is going to vary too much for any simple solution. I'd suggest going through your dois and working out which websites crop up the most, then one by one work out how to scrape the download link for those most common websites. If every website really is unique, as you say in the question, then there is no easy option. Maybe look for hrefs within elements that contain the text "Download" or "PDF"?

Comment: @AriCooper-Davis I guessed about this. The problem that I know very little about libraries & packages for work with web so I thought that there should be an elegant way to do such things.

Comment: @AriCooper-Davis As it turned out, there is a such elegant way :-)

Comment: or download from https://sci-hub.se/, this way you have only one webpage to deal with ;)

Comment: @alex There is a problem with captcha. Libgen has not this drawback but it has not all articles and the download speed is low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out, the most convenient way is to use `metapub` library. Note, that it demands **Visual Studio C++ 2015** and recenter.

```
import metapub
from urllib.request import urlretrieve

def downloadByDOI(doi, handle):
    def download(url, handle):
        try:
            urlretrieve(url, handle)
        except:
            download(url, handle)
    
    url = metapub.FindIt(doi=doi).url
    download(url, handle)
```